# How to attach a css style with a node in the node-edit form

Tags: 6, nodes, theming

I don't want to save the style in a file. What I want is to store the css code in a field while editing node and use the id or class within the node content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [css_injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector), it allows to add css only on specific pages, like 'node/add'.